# Getting group attributes for group name with special characters in Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, attributes, jndi

I have a group name which contains special characters.

```
CN=IN&T DC Gebnn/Dohn,OU=ABGroups,OU=Hammers,DC=MyCompany,DC=int
```

I am trying to get the attributes of this group using the following code:

```
String lstrFullGpName = CN=IN&T DC Gebnn/Dohn,OU=ABGroups,OU=Hammers,DC=MyCompany,DC=int;
Attributes groupAttributes = actxDir.getAttributes(lstrFullGpName);
```

This throws the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error
>   code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031006CC, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR),
>   data 0 ]; remaining name ' CN=IN&T DC
>   Gebnn/Dohn,OU=ABGroups,OU=Hammers,DC=MyCompany,DC=int'
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2987)
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
>   at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_lookup(LdapCtx.java:1011)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.c_resolveIntermediate_nns(ComponentContext.java:152)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.AtomicContext.c_resolveIntermediate_nns(AtomicContext.java:342)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_resolveIntermediate(ComponentContext.java:381)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:205)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:121)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:109)
>   at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:99)
>   at LDAPApp.main(LDAPApp.java:68)

I tried escaping the special characters, but that did not work. Any idea why this error could be occurring?

Comment: Very strange indeed. Here is what [MSDN siste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: ERROR_DS_MISSING_SUPREF
8406 (0x20D6)

 

No superior reference has been configured for the directory service. The directory service is therefore unable to issue referrals to objects outside this forest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution to this problem. Issues was with the DC in the user name.

Comment: I guess the "/" was your problem? Why, and how did you escape the DC to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known JNDI restriction:

> "If the LDAP entry's name contains [a forward slash], then you need to
>   escape it (using the backslash character ('\'))."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/jndi.html

I.e. instead of Java String `"/"`, one must use `"\\/"` in String constants, resp. escape Strings like this

```
distinguishedName = distinguishedName.replace("/", "\\/")
```